# How can I add a footer or any other content bellow a video that takes up 100% of the screen's height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish a very standard way of showing content with a video taking up 100% of the screen's height and a footer bellow it.

Instead of (1) I'm getting (2):

[image]

HTML:

```
  <section class="home">
    <video src="movie.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="footer">
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
.home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

.home video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4);
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    top: 1000;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 50;
    background: aqua;
}
```

How can I add a footer or any other content bellow a video that takes up 100% of the screen's height?

Comment: Why do you use `position: absolute` on the `.home` element? This takes the `.home` element out of flow. If `.footer` should appear after `.home` then this doesn't make to much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove:

```
.home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.home video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    top: 1000;
    left: 0;
}
```

Using **position: absolute** or **position: fixed** tells web browser to **not** "reserve" space in document structure for this element and makes your footer floating above video. According to https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-things-that-dont-occupy-space/ - *These elements are taken out of the document flow, so elements that appear after them in the source order will not flow around or below them.*

[image: absolutepositioning]

You have a simple layout and take a notice - div's are elements that takes all of the page's width by **default** and stack **one under another** so don't use any positioning here (except for overlay).

Something like this should work (with small improvements to do):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

.home {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

.home video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4);
}

.footer {
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 50;
    background: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have all three elements - .home, video, and .overlay have absolute positioning which is why the footer starts from the top.

Changing the position of `.home` to relative should work just fine.
And it would be better to remove the `top: 1000;` from the footer.

```
.home {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: #111;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

.home video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4);
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 50;
    background: aqua;
}
```